# When i change @SessionScoped to @ViewScoped i always got JDOM exception

Tags: jsf, session-scope, view-scope

i want to change the scope of one jsf page @SessionScoped to @ViewScoped but i always got this exception and i dont understand why.
I have check build path and dependency all seem good.
Stack error:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.JDOMException
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1952)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1411)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:69)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:481)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:455)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:455)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:352)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1130)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Some one can tell me how i can avoid/fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
...
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
```

It looks like you have a missing dependency (jar) in your web application.

Your application is configured such that your [view state](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/StateManager.html) is [being serialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) between requests while your session is retained in memory between requests.

Java loads classes lazily. The act of serializing your view-scoped bean is causing the resolution of a class (`JDOMException`) that is not required during normal execution of the type.